# App crash while calling RecyclerView says PID: 32217-Binary XML file error

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

logs are like this

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.notes, PID: 32217
>       android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean
>   java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
>       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on
>   a null object reference
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>           at com.example.notes.adapters.NotesRecyclerAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(NotesRecyclerAdapter.java:34)
>           at com.example.notes.adapters.NotesRecyclerAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(NotesRecyclerAdapter.java:18)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6794)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5975)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3641)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4194)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20967)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6440)
>           at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1183)
>           at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:870)
>           at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:889)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20967)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6440)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20967)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6440)
>           at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:446)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20967)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6440)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20967)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6440)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20967)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6440)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:955)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20967)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6440)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3092)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2779)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1863)
>   2019-09-24 16:50:58.474 32217-32217/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8072)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)

**NotesRecyclerAdapter.java**

```
public class NotesRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesRecyclerAdapter.NotesViewHolder> {

private static final String TAG = "NotesRecyclerAdapter";

private ArrayList<Note> mNotes ;

public NotesRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<Note> mNotes) {

    this.mNotes = mNotes;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public NotesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder: started");
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.note_list_item, parent, false);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder: created");
    return new NotesViewHolder(view);


}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NotesViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: started ");
    holder.notes_tv.setText(mNotes.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.time_tv.setText(mNotes.get(position).getTimeStamp());


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.d(TAG, "getItemCount: start");
    return mNotes.size();

}

public class NotesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView notes_tv, time_tv;
    public NotesViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        notes_tv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.notes_tv);
        time_tv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_tv);
        Log.d(TAG, "NotesViewHolder: ");

    }
}
}
```

this is the **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
//ui components
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

//var
 private NotesRecyclerAdapter mAdapter;
private  ArrayList<Note> noteArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
verticalSpacingItemDecorator verticalSpace;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Activity created ");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    initRecyclerView();
    insertFakeData();

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: done");

}



public void insertFakeData()
{

    for(int i = 0; i<=5; i++)
    {
        Note note = new Note();
       note.setTitle("title 1" );
        note.setContent("content #: 1");
       note.setTimeStamp("jan ");
       noteArrayList.add(note);
    }
    //to tell adapter to chk data set
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Log.d(TAG, "insertFakeData: inserted");
}

public  void initRecyclerView()

{
    Log.d(TAG, "initRecyclerView:  started");
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    verticalSpace = new verticalSpacingItemDecorator(10);
   mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(verticalSpace);
    mAdapter = new NotesRecyclerAdapter(noteArrayList);  //setting adapter with empty dataset
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    Log.d(TAG, "initRecyclerView:  done");

}
}
```

Not able to find the solution, by debugging, I found that onBindViewHolder() is never being called

Comment: this is an inflate exception, take a look in your xmls

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: yes, found the XML file error (lower case of view instead of View ) ,Thanks

Answer (score -1):

in the XML file

i changed view to View
this helped me in removing this error

"PID: 32217
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference"